# How to display error message using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to validate login page ,having fields email and password,,i have written code using if else condition but systyem.out.println() statement is not displayed in console.

```
package AdminPAge;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LoginPageValidation {

public static void main(String[]args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
    "C:\\Users\\UMASHANKAR\\Documents\\selenuim\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/dashboard");
    WebElement email=driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
    WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.name("password"));

    email.sendKeys("admin@malbork.in");
    password.sendKeys("NsSaNj@0205");

     if(email!=null && password!=null) {

        driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();  

     }else 
    {
        System.out.println("password field is required ");
    }
}}

   //main logic      

    `enter code here`WebElement email=driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
    WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.name("password"));

     email.sendKeys("admin@malbork.in");
     password.sendKeys("NsSaNj@0205");

     if(email!=null && password!=null) {

        driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();  

     }else 
    {
        System.out.println("password field is required ");
    }
```

if email and password fields are blank then error message must be displayed in console like email field is required.also validate email field with valid pattern means regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code you are looking whether fields email and password exists on the login page, You don't read whether fields are blank or not. Since login page will have email and password entering text boxes, always else block wont be executed.

As I understood your requirement, You need to read the field as below and check whether its blank

> driver.findElement(By.name("password")).getText();